# Running Time of Algorithm - If statements inside While loop

Tags: algorithm, if-statement, math, while-loop, big-o

I have this example

```
A = 2,1,8,4,3,6 // c1, n 
n = 6 // c2, n
i = 1 // c3, n
H = 2 // c4, n
inv = 0 // c5, n
while H <= n    // c6, n(n+1)/2-1               
    if A[i] > A[H] && !H = n // c7, n(n-1)/2
        inv = inv + 1
        H = H + 1 
    else if A[i] > A[H] && H = n // c10, n(n-1)/2
        inv = inv + 1
        i = i + 1
        H = i + 1
    else if A[i] < A[H] && !H = n // c14, n(n-1)/2
        H = H + 1
    else if A[i] < A[H] && H = n // c16, n(n-1)/2
        i = i + 1 
        H = i + 1
print inv // c19, n
```

My question is how many `n` times will the code inside the if statements run in this example?

Comment: "fine gentlemen"? The site is gender equal.

Comment: ohh sorry did not mean to disrespect the other gender. Will change it imediately

Comment: "My question is ... " sounds suspiciously like "My homework question is ... ". Why should we do your homework for you?

Comment: you sound like a nice guy John. Im sorry to hear you wont help me solve my homework now that im hoving trouble solving them. As you can see in the above example i have tried to solve this on my own and the textbook doesn't mention anything about the issue i have atm.

Comment: Won't you have an infinite loop if none of the conditions are met? What is `H` or `!H` - is it is a number?

Comment: If something is homework, you should indicate it as such and describe what you have done and where you are stuck. Perhaps not you personally, but a great many students try to use Stack Overflow as a way of getting others to do homework for them, rather than as a way to get help. If you want help, describe your efforts in more detail. Nothing in your post suggests that you tried anything on your own. The cryptic comments perhaps?

Comment: i will bear that in mind for next time John. For now rest assured im not asking you to complete my homework. The assignment is to calculate the runtime of this algorithme in general. I am only asking for help for the content inside the if statements of this algorithme.

Comment: This hangs in an infinite loop if you ever have `A[i] == A[H]`. Are there assumptions on `A` that rules this out? Also -- since everything inside the loop is inside an if statement, are you simply trying to find how many times the loop runs?

Answer (score 0):

First, to understand this code, some assumptions must be made:

1. The array *A* is 1-indexed based, i.e. the first element is accessed as *A[1]*.
2. The elements in *A* are unique - duplicate values are not allowed.
3. The expression `!H = n` means *H is not equal to n*

The loop condition is *H <= n*, so let's see when this could become false.

We can see that as long as *H < n*, an iteration will increment *H* with one (either in the first `if` block, or in the third).

When *H* reaches *n*, *i* is incremented (and only then), and *H* becomes *i+1* (in the second or last `if` block).

At one point *i* will become *n*, and then *H* will be set to *i+1* again, which is the only way *H* can get a value that is greater than *n*, at which point the loop stops.

So, in other words, this loop makes *i* go from 1 to *n*, and for each of those values of *i*, *H* runs from *n+1* to *n*. 
This really means the tuple *(i,H)* takes all possible pairs from the range *1...n* where *i < H*. This number of pairs is thus *n(n-1)/2* (also noted *C(n,2)*).

In the example *n = 6*, so the number of pairs (iterations) is *6(6-1)/2 = 15*.

The following JavaScript implementation demonstrates that a loop counter indeed reaches the count of 15:

```js
// Must add an element at index 0, since the 
// original code assumes 1-based indexing
A = [null,2,1,8,4,3,6] // c1, n 
n = 6 // c2, n
i = 1 // c3, n
H = 2 // c4, n
inv = 0 // c5, n
loopCounter = 0
while (H <= n) {    // c6, n(n+1)/2-1               
    loopCounter++; // count it!!
    if (A[i] > A[H] && H != n) { // c7, n(n-1)/2
        inv = inv + 1
        H = H + 1 
    } else if (A[i] > A[H] && H == n) { // c10, n(n-1)/2
        inv = inv + 1
        i = i + 1
        H = i + 1
    } else if (A[i] < A[H] && H != n) { // c14, n(n-1)/2
        H = H + 1
    } else if (A[i] < A[H] && H == n) { // c16, n(n-1)/2
        i = i + 1 
        H = i + 1
    } 
}        
console.log('inv = ', inv) // c19, n
console.log('iterations = ', loopCounter)
```